# Source code button on htmleditor Extjs 4.0

Tags: javascript, extjs, html-editor

When i edit some data on the html view i got no problem to submit it and save it but when i switch to the source code view it doesn't submit the changes i do.

The init of the htmleditor looks like this:

```
Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.init();
    var html = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.HtmlEditor', {
        renderTo: 'content_ext',
        width: 800,
        height: 300,
        listeners: {
            render: function(me,content){ me.setValue(Ext.get('form_content_html').dom.value); },
            sync: function(me,content){ Ext.get('form_content_html').dom.value = content; }
        }
    });
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In source code view text there is plain textarea underneath. API tells that sync is fired when the textarea is updated with content from the editor, so maybe you should bind to another event? Try keydown on textarea:

```
render: function(){
    this.textareaEl.on('keydown', function() {
        /* do sth */
    }, this, { buffer: 100 });
}
```